# Android background random shrinking

Tags: android, background

Randomly while phone is asleep and wallpaper rotation enabled, the wallpaper will shrink in size with a black border around. Setting a new wallpaper causes the screen to be black. Using PeekDrawable though shows that the correct wallpaper is set and is what the system says should be the current wallpaper. Only way to fix so far has been a reboot at which point the expected wallpaper will show..

Has anyone seen this behavior before and if so do you know what is happening. It never occurs on a emulator, only on my testing phone. Testing phone is a Samsung Galaxy S using ADW launcher. I have downloaded two other launchers to see if replicated, but as is a seemingly random occurrence it has not happened so far on GoLauncher or Nova Launcher.

Comment: It happened again last night and when i turned on phone was completely black. Switching between home programs went ADW > Trebuchet > Nova > Go. On the switch to GoLauncher the background, which peekdraawable said was there, showed. This is leading me to believe it is a system issue of some kind. I am using cyanogenmod for the latest version possible. I will now revert to stock ROM and see if I can replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was the ROM. Hellybean based on cyanogenmod had issues regarding this. After extensive testing going back to stock and then through the released updates for device, as well as a couple other ROMS (Fasty II and III, etc) the issue only occurred in that version of HellyBean.